# "Fail to convert to internal representation" while accessing changed column data with audit query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using envers in my project to audit data.

Now I want to access changed data with audit query.

My pojo class for table is below

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag=true)
@Table(name = "INSTRUMENT", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "INSTRUMENT_NAME"))
public class Instrument implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long instrumentId;
    private String instrumentName;
    private WorkflowState workflowState;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INSTRUMENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public long getInstrumentId() {
        return this.instrumentId;
    }

    public void setInstrumentId(long instrumentId) {
        this.instrumentId = instrumentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "INSTRUMENT_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getInstrumentName() {
        return this.instrumentName;
    }

    public void setInstrumentName(String instrumentName) {
        this.instrumentName = instrumentName;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    public WorkflowState getWorkflowState() {
        return this.workflowState;
    }

    public void setWorkflowState(WorkflowState workflowState) {
        this.workflowState = workflowState;
    }
}
```

Now I tried to access this with audit query as

```
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Instrument.class, false, true)
.add(AuditEntity.property("status").hasChanged());
List list= query.getResultList();
```

So at the time of accessing **getResultList()** , Its throwing Exception as follows

```
 SqlExceptionHelper: Fail to convert to internal representation
```

I figured it out, this is because in my db **Instrument.status** column is as String data Type. While here I am using Join.

So please tell me how to write query to resolve this problem

**PROBLEM** is How to write Audit Query if my table has foreign key (class property have join dependency).

Join table **WorkflowState** discription is as follows

```
public class WorkflowState implements java.io.Serializable {

private BigDecimal stateId;
private Workflow workflow;
private String stateName;

//getters and setters
```

And it has a join column too i.e "workflow" .

Comment: If it's a string in DB, u have to make it string in your class.

Comment: @EanV That's not correct, the issue is that the user isn't using the API correctly.  They should be providing the _property name_ rather than the _column name_ as the argument to `AuditEntity#property`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `workflowState` rather than `status`.  The API is based on you specifying the property name and not the column name.

Comment: Yes, this is fine with **workflowState** property, but if I pass other property to check changes for as   `AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Instrument.class, false, true)
.add(AuditEntity.property("instrumentName").hasChanged());

List list= query.getResultList();`   
then it throws the same exception too

Comment: What to do with that case (previous comment), Is there anything else I have to add in Query ?

Comment: If you are querying the `Instrument` class directly and checking whether audited properties of that class were modified, that should work.  Based on the query you've shown, that shouldn't be throwing an error.  What is the database column type and what database are you using?

Comment: I am using **oracle 11g** database. And the data type of the columns is as `number` for `instrumnetId` , `string` for `instrumentName` and `string` for `status` where I have taken **status**  as a join here(as shown in the question).

Comment: Search everywhere related to this issue but didn't find anything, I am doing same as mention in docs, but not getting why this exception is coming, this query is fine with the table that don't have join,  this force me to move for manual coding,

Comment: Well your post doesn't show a join, so its hard to help without seeing what you're circumstances and code looks like.

Comment: See in my **Instrument** DAO class, for status column  I have used ManyToOne() join with WorkflowState. I have included that code in question.

Comment: The fact its a `@ManyToOne` shouldn't matter.  In your `Instrument` audit table, there should be a column named `workflowState_MOD` or equivalent if you've changed the prefix/suffix via configuration.  If that field isn't present then either your schema was generated incorrectly or you're using an older version of Envers that has a bug.

Comment: Schema is generating correctly, and all others Envers queries are fine with this except this one, and table and column name shouldn't matter, problem is with their types. I think this query is not for the table which have join condition, One should check  it Envers with join condition.

Comment: I am using 5.2.10 version

Comment: If you think its a bug, open a jira issue at https://hibernate.atlassian.net and provide a runnable test case so I can fix the issue.  But based the code in your post, the query executes fine on 5.2.10 and the soon to be 5.2.11.